# Negative top and left positioning based on 50% content height and width

Tags: html, css

Given a relative black box within the white box here:

[image]

I'm looking to offset the black box with negative top and left positioning.

[image]

Is it possible to offset the black box via the content inside?

Answer (score 2):

Use `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` to move the white box up and to the left 50% of it's overall width/height.

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}
div {
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

span {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>asdf asdf<br>asdfasdf<br>fooooo<br>barrr</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this answer. The only issue im having is that these boxes both have set heights and widths, and Im interested in having the black box offset 50% based on dynamic content.

Comment: @ThomasReggi you're welcome. when you make a post on stack overflow, we need a [mcve] if you have code you're working with. If you don't provide that, best I can do is guess at whatever your code is. That said, `translate()` works off of the dimensions of the element it's applied to whether it's fixed or dynamic. I removed the fixed size and just put some content. Does that work? If not, show me the code you're working with and what exactly you want that code to look like.